# How can install software with tar.gz file?

Tags: software-installation, tar

Here is the way i install zulu jdk:

```
wget https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu18.32.13-ca-jdk18.0.2.1-linux_x64.tar.gz
mv zulu18.32.13-ca-jdk18.0.2.1-linux_x64.tar.gz    /opt
cd /opt
tar -zxvf zulu18.32.13-ca-jdk18.0.2.1-linux_x64.tar.gz
vim ~/.bash_profile
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/zulu18.32.13-ca-jdk18.0.2.1-linux_x64
export CLASSPATH=$:CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin    
source   ~/.bash_profile
```

All files stored in `/opt/zulu18.32.13-ca-jdk18.0.2.1-linux_x64`.

```
sudo ls  /opt/zulu18.32.13-ca-jdk18.0.2.1-linux_x64
bin  conf  demo  DISCLAIMER  include  jmods  legal  lib  man  readme.txt  release  Welcome.html
```

I want to store `/opt/zulu18.32.13-ca-jdk18.0.2.1-linux_x64/bin`  in `/usr/bin`,i knew i can make a link to point to `/usr/bin`,can tar command extract and save `/opt/zulu18.32.13-ca-jdk18.0.2.1-linux_x64/bin`  in `/bin` ,`/opt/zulu18.32.13-ca-jdk18.0.2.1-linux_x64/lib`  in `/lib`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are just archive files. You can extract them wherever you want.

Extracting them in a location that their contents sit next to your system installed files is a recipe for disaster, however.

When you ship binary software, you typically have to ship the libraries that uses in exactly the right version, as the user's system might not have them in the same version as your development system, or at all.

So, you replicate a typical Linux filesystem tree and put all the things you need inside there, have a few lines of shell code that bend a few paths where libraries and executables are looked for, and are good to go.

However, merging the user's "native" system with that tree will lead to you overwriting some of the user's libraries, settings files, and programs. And that will break the user's system.

So, don't do that. End of story.